# ThreeJS State Object

Tags: javascript, game, state

state object - a state or scene from the game. When the start function is called, the state starts rendering, shutting down any other state using the renderer, and calling the specified functions (init, update, etc.) as necessary.

state constructor - given an object definitions, it overrides the object's default settings and functions with the ones specified in definitions. the autostart parameter, usually true in the first state, determines whether the state automatically starts rendering, or whether start must be called.

This abstraction is meant to make managing multiple states much easier when using ThreeJS, and it also makes pausing and bootstrapping the game easier.

```
'use strict';

var State = function (definitions, autostart) {
  var keys = Object.keys(definitions);
  for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
    this[ keys[i] ] = definitions[ keys[i] ];
  }

  var paused = false;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'isPaused', {
    get: function () {
      return paused;
    },

    set: function (value) {
      paused = !!value;

      if (paused) { this.paused();   }
      else        { this.unpaused(); }
    }
  });

  if (autostart) { this.start(); }
};

State.prototype = {
  camera:   null,
  renderer: null,
  scene:    null,
  fps:      60,

  init:     function () {},
  update:   function () {},
  shutdown: function () {},

  paused:   function () {},
  unpaused: function () {},
  resize:   function () {},

  start: function () {
    var that = this;

    if (!this.renderer || !this.renderer.hasOwnProperty('render')) { throw 'Renderer must implement a \'render\' function.'; }
    if (typeof this.renderer.__stateId === 'undefined') { this.renderer.__stateId = 0; }

    var myId = (this.renderer.__stateId += 1);

    this.init();

    function tick() {
      if (that.renderer.__stateId === myId) {
        that.renderer.render(that.scene, that.camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
      }
    } requestAnimationFrame(tick);

    var time = Date.now(), interval = 1000 / this.fps;
    function instance() {
      if (that.renderer.__stateId === myId) {
        if (!that.isPaused) { that.update(); }
      } else { return that.shutdown(); }

      time += interval;
      setTimeout(instance, interval + time - Date.now() );
    } setTimeout(instance, interval);


    function resizeListener() {
      if (that.renderer.__stateId === myId) {

        that.resize( that.renderer.domElement.clientWidth,
                     that.renderer.domElement.clientHeight );

      } else { window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener, false); }
    }          window.addEventListener   ('resize', resizeListener, false);

    return this.renderer.domElement;
  }
};
```

Sorry for posting so much code, but I have a few questions.

1. Is the isPaused variable declaration style bad practice? Is there a better way?
2. Should renderer.render be merged into the normal update loop rather than using requestAnimationFrame?
3. Is there an alternative to renderer.__stateId ? It looks pretty bad from a 'only modify your own objects' perspective.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  This isn't a lot of code from our perspective--we review whole programs routinely.  It would help though if you could give more of a description of what problem the code solves.  I.e. if you asked someone to write it, what would you say?  It's also helpful if you can give an example of how the code is called.  For example, what are typical values for `dimensions` and `autostart`?  A link to [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) might also be appropriate.